# Using if statement to check bool value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a bool variable in my model and I want to check it. If true I want to show users certain HTML, and the ones that have it false other HMTL. User Model is where all the user info is stored. Keys Model is where table data is stored.

view model:

```
public partial class User
{
    public bool Addon { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to put an if statement in the `_NavBar` View. Code is as follows

```
@model Vidly2.Models.User


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    bool admin = Model.Addon;
}

@if (admin)
{     
 *HTML Code*
}
else
{
  *HTML Code*
}
```

Post Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Autherize(Vidly2.Models.User userModel)
{
    using (LoginDataBaseEntities db = new LoginDataBaseEntities())
    {
        var userDetails = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == userModel.Email && x.Password == userModel.Password).FirstOrDefault();
        if (userDetails == null)
        {
            userModel.LoginErrorMessage = "Wrong username or password.";
            return View("Index", userModel);
        }
        else {
            Session["userID"] = userDetails.Email;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Keys");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

The error I get is as follows -

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item
>   passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Vidly2.Models.ViblyyKeyy]', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Vidly2.Models.User'.

Source Error:

```
Line 9:  </head>
Line 10: <body>
Line 11:     @Html.Partial("_NavBar")
Line 12:     <div class="container body-content">
Line 13:         @RenderBody()
```

How could I change the if statement to work? Is there problems with types?

Thank you for solving issue.

Comment: Exception says you are passing other object to razor page. Where is your controller post method?
If you were indeed passing User class, Your code should be working fine

Comment: I had added post method

Comment: It's possible that this error it's releated to another partial or a controller that is rendered  in or before `_NavBar`. I would suggest to search for `ViblyyKeyy` model in your solution and track it down fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is not anything wrong with your if statement. Actually Your query is passing a `List<Vidly2.Models.ViblyyKeyy>` to the view, but the view expects `Vidly2.Models.User`. So you need to either change your C# code to pass a new instance of `Vidly2.Models.User` to your View, or change your view to accept a `List<Vidly2.Models.ViblyyKeyy>` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has helped me figure out where the error is coming from. I have posted the method above. Quite unsure on what to change to make it return `Vidly.Models.User`.

Comment: Yes, I ended up going a different route. Your explanation help me find where my code was breaking though. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change This Line

```
@model Vidly2.Models.User
```

To

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly2.Models.User>
```

syntax

```
@model IEnumerable<projectname.Models.class name which you want to access here>
```

Comment: In that case he should also change "bool admin = Model.Addon;"

Comment: @ATT yes exactly because boolean have by default value